# Datastructure to use for storing a huge list of long values

Tags: java, performance, caching, data-structures

I am caching list of Long indexes in my Java program and it is causing the memory to overflow.
So, decided to cache only the start and end indexes of all continuous indexes and rewrite the ArrayList's required APIs. Now, what data structure will be best here to implement the start-end index cache? Is it better to go for TreeMap and keep start index as key and end index as value?

Comment: Can you give at least some examples of your data? It is very difficult to understand what is the issue you are having.

Comment: @mvp: Yup, I've deleted my answer on a second reading - there really isn't enough information to help yet...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?What operations do you want from this data structure?

Comment: This is for creating a search index. This list will store the indx of elements found after a search. Operations are similar to that of an ArrayList. But I cant use ArrayList to store all elements since it overflows after probable 20 million Long values.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use some variation of bit string storage.

In Java bit strings are implemented by [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

For example, to represent arbitrary list of unique 32-bit integers, you could store it as a single bit string 4 billion bits long, so this will take 4 bln / 8 bits = 512MB of memory. This is a lot, but it is *worst possible case*.

But, you can be a lot smarter than that. For example, you could store it as list or binary tree of some smaller fixed (or dynamic) sized bit strings, say 65536 bits or less (or 8KB or less). In other words, each leaf object in this tree will have small header representing start offset and length (probably power of 2 for simplicity, but it does not have to be), and bit string storing actual array members. For efficiency, you could optionally compress this bit string using gzip or similar algorithm - it will make access slower, but could improve memory efficiency by factor of 10 or more.

If your 20 million index elements are almost consecutive (not very sparse), it should take only around 20mln/8bits ~= 2 million bits = 2 MB to represent it in memory. If you gzip it, it will be probably under 1MB overall.

Answer (score 0):

The most compact representation will depend greatly on the distribution of indices in your specific application.

If your indices are densely clustered, the range-based representation suggested by mvp will probably work well (you might look at implementations of run-length encoding for raster graphics, since they're similar problems).

If your indices aren't clustered in dense runs, that encoding will actually increase memory consumption. For sparsely-populated lists, you might look into primitive data structures such as LongArrayList or LongOpenHashSet in [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/), or similar structures in [Gnu Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) or [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/). In most VMs, each Long object in your ArrayList consumes 20+ bytes, whereas a primitive long consumes only 8. So you can often realize a significant memory savings with type-specific primitive collections instead of the standard Collections framework.

I've been very pleased with FastUtil, but you might find another solution suits you better. A little simulation and memory profiling should help you determine the most effective representation for your own data.

Answer (score 0):

Most BitSet (compressed or uncompressed) implementations are for integers. Here's one for longs: http://www.censhare.com/en/aktuelles/censhare-labs/yet-another-compressed-bitset which works like an ordered primitive long hash set or long to long hash map.